# Play Framework JSON Conversion

Tags: json, play-json

I'm planning to use the Play JSON library to Serialize and De-Serialize objects to and from Json. I have a case class like this:

```
case class MyCaseClass(string: String, intVal: Int)
```

I have a service that returns me a JSON String which effectively is a Seq[MyCaseClass]. I can put this String into a JsValue, but how could I convert this JsValue into MyCaseClass?

```
def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[MyCaseClass]] = {
  ???
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply defining `reads` as `Json.format[MyCaseClass]`? If the names of the properties match the names in the json you are reading, that should work.